# Can able to install Linux Headers (Kali Linux)?

Tags: kernel, package-management, kali-linux, aptitude

How to install Kali Linux header? I used this command `apt-get update && apt-get install -y linux-headers-$(uname -r)`, but it was showing the below error

```
E:unable to locate package linux-headers-4.6.0-kali1-686 pae'
E: could not find any package by glob 'linux-headers-4.6.0-kali1-686 pae'
E: could not find any package by regex 'linux-headers-4.6.0-kali1-686 pae'
```

Answer (score 1):

Open the `sources.list` file:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Add the following line (carefully):

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
```

Save it then run the following commands :

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-cache search linux-headers
```

Then install the appropriate linux-headers:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

Comment: I wonder why is it so?

Comment: @DenisKa Because there are no entries in his sources.list repository.